# Deploying a TCP based WCF service, that's hosted in a Windows service

Tags: wcf, windows-services

I've finished writing a WCF service that uses TCP.  It is meant to run on a Windows 2003 Server, which doesn't have WAS available, so I've written a Windows service to host my WCF service.  It works great on my development machine.

Now, how do I get these two services onto the Windows 2003 Server?  Do I just copy the WCF service there and that's it?  I would think it would probably be best if I put it into some specific location, but where would that be?  And then the hosting Windows service, how do I deploy that to the Windows 2003 Server?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a service deployment project that you've used in the Dev area.
It will be the same technique.

[Example of creating a service in c# from codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/WindowsService.aspx)

put it in program files\Your Service

Comment: Shoot.  I think you're right.  That's the problem with only having a chance to work on this thing once every 3 months, there's so much I forget as time goes by...

Comment: OK, I just double checked, and I don't have a deployment project as a part of the solution.  Instead what I did was used the svrutil to generate a project, incorporated that into the Windows service project, and when I went to register the Windows service on my development machine I used installutil.

So, how do I do the same thing on the server?